# ZXing barcode iphone error

Tags: objective-c, ios4, zxing

i'm trying to import the zxing into my project but i am getting the following :

```
   can't open -exported_symbols_list file: /zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/exportList
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: was that a joke? -.-, how do i make it open

Answer (score 0):

Which guide dou you use to import the framework? I reccoment this [one](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README?r=1750).

Answer taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README?r=1409):

> Ultimately you need to make a tweak so that ZXing actually decodes
>   barcode. In target section, double
>        click on your project target, and go to the build tab. Look for
>   the "Exported Symbols Files" and
>        double-click on it. Att the relative path to the exportList files
>   in "**/zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/exportList**".
>        This will tell the linket to actually link with some key classes
>   so that this code registers the necessary
>        decoders.